# How do I check whether a custom statistic passed to gtsummary's add_stat() is on the label or level location?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm currently building a custom function to evaluate pairwise differences between groups in tbl_summary/tbl_svysummary.
When using `%>% add_stat(fns = everything() ~ custom_stat, location = ~"level"`, the function should return a df where nrow is equal to the number of levels of a given categorical variable, while `location = ~"label"` should return a single row.
I'm not picking up on the `location` argument being passed to `custom_stat`, so how do I get that information in order to format the output accordingly?

I have searched through the gtsummary documentation and other requests/questions but have been unable to find an answer.

---

REPREX:

Let's take the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

print_one <- function(data, variable, by, tbl, loc = "label", ...) {
  if (loc == "label") {
    return(tibble(Res = 1))
  } else {
    if (class(data[[variable]]) != "character" & class(data[[variable]]) != "factor" ) {
      return(tibble(Res = c()))
    } else {
      tibble(Res = 1:length(unique(data[[variable]])))
    }
  }
}

trial %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt, include = c(age, stage)) %>% 
  add_stat(fns = everything() ~ print_one, location = ~ "level")
```

I want a way to forward the gtsummary `location` argument (i.e., either the value `"label"` or `"level"` into the `print_one` function, so that when `location = ~ "label"` I get the following output:

[image: The tbl_summary output with the no. 1 at each variable]

and when `location = ~ "level"` it should be:

[image: The tbl_summary output with running counts at each level of categorical variables]

So my question is: How do I get the `"loc"` argument in my `print_one` function to receive the value of the `"location"` argument of gtsummary's `add_stat` function?

EDIT: Add-on question:
Is there a way to manually specify additional arguments (i.e., the `"loc"` argument) to the `print_one` function when I call it in `%>% add_stat(fns = everything() ~ print_one)`?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Can you please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (aka a reprex) to illustrate your question?

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I have updated my question now, hope that clears it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after prodding around more I came to the conclusion that intercepting the value of the `location` argument by the `print_one()` function was not possible.

Instead, I came up with a different way to apply the function to allow users to specify the `location`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

print_one <- function(data, variable, location) {
  if (location == "label") {
    return(tibble(Res = 1))
  } else {
    if (class(data[[variable]]) != "character" & class(data[[variable]]) != "factor" ) {
      return(tibble(Res = c()))
    } else {
      tibble(Res = 1:length(unique(data[[variable]])))
    }
  }
}

apply_print_one <- function(tbl, location = "label") {
  fun <- function(data, variable, by, tbl, ...) {
    print_one(data, variable, location)
  }
  tbl %>% add_stat(fns = everything() ~ fun, location = ~ location)
}

trial %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt, include = c(age, stage)) %>% 
  apply_print_one("level")
```

That way, calling `apply_print_one()` creates a temporary function `fun` which calls `print_one()` with the right argument values *and* supplies the same `location` parameter to `add_stat()` all at once - while making the code look neater to users.